# Follow system returning User matching query does not exist error

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

I have been working on a follow system on django which needs to have the same functionality as instagram's one; meaning that a user can follow and be followed by other other users and in a user's profile there is a follower count that displays the number of followers a user has, together with a following count that displays the number of people a user is following.

So everything was working good and there was one missing functionality to complete the follow system and it was the follower count. To get this done, I created a signals.py file, but as soon as I did that The follow/unfollow button was not working due to a internal server 500 error, so after some investigation I realized that the 500 error was happening because there is this error `DoesNotExist at /accounts/follow/username User matching query does not exist.` Why is it poping that error, can it be solved?

signals.py

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender = Following.followed.through) # which list is changed
def add_follower(sender, instance, action, reverse, pk_set, **kwargs):
    followed_users = [] # list of users main (logged ) user have followed
    logged_user = User.objects.get(username = instance) # user who followed other users
    for i in pk_set:
        user = User.objects.get(pk = i)
        following_obj = Following.objects.get(user = user)
        followed_users.append(following_obj)

    if action == "pre_add":
        for i in followed_users:
            i.follower.add(logged_user)
            i.save()

    if action == "pre_remove":
        for i in followed_users:
            i.follower.remove(logged_user)
            i.save()
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    connection = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    follower = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followed")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follower")

    @classmethod
    def follow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.add(another_account)
        print("followed")

    @classmethod
    def unfollow(cls, user, another_account):
        obj, create = cls.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
        obj.followed.remove(another_account)
        print("unfollowed")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

views.py

```
def follow(request, username):
    main_user = request.user
    to_follow = User.objects.get(username=username)
    following = Following.objects.filter(user = main_user, followed = to_follow)
    is_following = True if following else False 

    if is_following:
        Following.unfollow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = False
    else:
        Following.follow(main_user, to_follow)
        is_following = True
    resp = {
        'following': is_following,
    }

    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")

def profile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    if user:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        user = user[0]
        is_following = Following.objects.filter(user=request.user, followed=user)
        following_obj = Following.objects.get(user=user)
        follower = following_obj.follower.count()
        following = following_obj.followed.count()
        args1 = {
            'user_obj':user,
            'post_owner': post_owner,
            'follower': follower,
            'following': following,
            'connection': is_following,
        }

    else: return HttpResponse("NO SUCH USER")

    return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)
```

profile.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% if connection %}
    <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' user_obj.username %}">Unfollow</a>
{% elif not connection %}
    <a type="button" class="button-caballo" id="follow" role="button" href="{% url 'follow' user_obj.username %}">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#follow").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $.ajax({
            url : href,
            success : function(response){
                if(response["following"]){
                    $("#follow").html("Unfollow");
                }
                else{
                    $("#follow").html("Follow");
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\startup\gstartup\accounts\views.py", line 110, in follow
    Following.unfollow(main_user, to_follow)
  File "C:\Users\USER\startup\gstartup\accounts\models.py", line 43, in unfollow
    obj.followed.remove(another_account)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 961, in remove
    self._remove_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1179, in _remove_items
    signals.m2m_changed.send(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\USER\startup\gstartup\accounts\signals.py", line 16, in add_follower
    logged_user = User.objects.get(username = instance) # user who followed other users
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\startup\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

If you have any questions or need to see more code please let meknow in the comments;)

Comment: Found this line: `File "C:\Users\USER\startup\gstartup\accounts\signals.py", line 16, in add_follower
    logged_user = User.objects.get(username = instance) # user who followed other users` what is the `instance` doing there?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 instance is the user that is logged in that is why it is on the logged_user variable so that it can be called I guess. I dont really know if that should go there I am following a tutorial which is in hindi and I dont understand what that guy says

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala Can you create a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala could you tell me which function is calling add_follower()? And the values being passed to it when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confuse about the `sender`, but I am pretty sure your instance variable is an object of User class and for filtering you should use

```
logged_user = User.objects.get(username = instance.username)
```

note1: If `instance` is an `User` instance, I don't see why the query is needed.

note2: If it's not an `User` instance, check it's class and use field name instead of instance.

Answer (score 0):

## DoesNotExist Error

The issue you seem to be encountering is here:

`to_follow = User.objects.get(username=username)` located in your views.py.

This will raise a `DoesNotExist` error and respond with a `500` if object is not found. Consider using [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead.

Consider removing the signal. Count method as detailed in the example below should be efficient enough. If any more is necessary consider higher level caching solution instead.

## Idiosyncrasies

- Consider using a [custom User
  model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)
  instead of Profiles.
- Consider using [manager
  methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)
  instead of class methods.
- Consider using [class based
  views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/)
  with mixins and separating business logic into contextual methods to
  make unit testing and debugging easier.
- Consider writing [unit
  tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/)
  for each of your model and view methods to more easily identify bugs
  when they happen.

Your models.py should be refactored to the something resembling the following to reduce complexity and increase data integrity:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def follow(user, user_to_follow):
      obj, created = self.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
      return self.profile.following.add(user, user_to_follow)

    def unfollow(self, user)
      obj, created = self.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
      return self.following.remove(profile, user_to_unfollow)


class User(AbstractUser):
    connection = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(self, "following")
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(self, "followers")

    objects = UserManager()

    def follower_count(self):
      return User.objects.filter(following=self).count()

    def following_count(self):
      return User.objects.filter(followers=self).count()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'


# Profile.objects.follow(user, user_to_follow)
# Profile.objects.unfollow(user, user_to_follow)
# profile.follower_count()
# profile.following_count()
```

## References

[get object or 404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Custom User Models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Manager Methods: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods

Unit Tests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/

Unit Test for View example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/#testing-the-detailview

DetailView code example for domain logic separation: https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/views/generic/detail.py#L8-L100

Class based views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/